# Is it possible to insert custom data in phone call initialization?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, gsm, phone-call

I want to send some custom flag when user initiate call with other user(s). On the other side I would install app that will catch call when it is in status ringing and I want to read that flag. Basically I want to use some space within package, that is titled as *free data form* (that is only info I got so far).

This is going to be Android and/or iPhone app. Anything that will work.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Are you saying that you need to send a flag along with a phone call. For ex: If A call B, then along with the call you want to send a flag say 'y', correct?

Comment: Yes, and it does not need to go with every package (when call is in progress), it's okay if I send it only until other party picks up.

Comment: It's not possible via the GSM/UMTS call protocols - they are too low level and don't include space for own data.  Maybe a cloud service?

Comment: What about LTE? I can go over some sort of cloud based service, but I need synchronization.

Comment: I' m not aware of any direct method to do what you require over standard GSM, 3G or LTE signalling. PBX's often have similar requirements if you want a telecoms like reference for this type of thing but they are usually trunk signalling protocol based. There may be other ways to achieve your goals if you give more background - for example, is your use case a closed user group, i.e. you only need this extra signalling for members of a particular organisation?

Comment: I found out there is part of gsm call message that is marked as free data. Do you know how I can utilize that. Use case is very simple, lets send a 8bit long data along with call.

Comment: @TheLittleHawk - there are quit a few messages at different layers involved in establishing an end to end GSM call - can you let us know which message you are referring? It may be the 'free data' part of the message will make more sense in context.